# Linux stuck on boot about EHCI

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, mac, acpi

Apple Mac Mini 2009 version. Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 on x86_64 worked fine but after some 14.04 update becomes to show this issue while is booting (16.04 has the same issue):

```
...
[XXXX] PPP generic driver 2.4.3
[XXXX] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[XXXX] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[XXXX] ehci-pci: 0000:00:04.1: EHCI Host Controller
[XXXX] ehci-pci: 0000:00:04.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[XXXX] ehci-pci: 0000:00:04.1: debug port 1
[XXXX] ehci-pci: 0000:00:04.1: irq 22, io mem 0xd3489200
```

The [dirty workaround](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/ubuntu-fails-to-boot-after-dist-upgrade-4175516068/#post5513591%20dirty) is to add `acpi=off` as kernel parameter but I miss all the ACPI stuff: power management...

The same problem is detected on [Mac Book Pro models](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2288334)

Comment: Try to run back to older kernel version. This issue is probably hardware-kernel related.

Comment: @Eska, I have tried it, but no lock. I keep an old kernel 3.8 from Ubuntu Raring in the hard disk but the boot stucks in the ACPI init (IRQ 17).

Answer (score 3):

You can try two things:

#### Easy Solution

Just unplug (from electricity) your computer for 10 seconds,
plug again and it might work! (yes it does)

#### If that doesn't work, edit GRUB

The solution was in GRUB

- Go to **Advanced Options**
- Select `Recovery mode` option
- press <kbd>e</kbd> to go to the editor.
- edit to include `nomodeset` and `acpi=off` in the kernel boot line

  ```
  linux /vmlinuz-3.0.2..... nomodeset acpi=off
  ```

  press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

That way it did boot, but it didn't recognize the keyboard.

This confirmed it was an `acpi` issue.

The next thing I did is restart the computer and tested the different acpi options in [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI#Debugging_procedure).

The one that did it for me (add to kernel boot line in GRUB as before) was

```
nolapic
```

<kbd>F10</kbd> once again and then my keyboard responded. From there I ran `fsck`, and restarted again.